# How to make a tuple give a random new tuple?

Tags: class, random, f#, mutable

I am trying to take a position (a,b) and via the code receive a random new position (a,b).. I am having great trouble implementing the code and what I got is by far my best try..

```
type Teleport (a,b) = 
    inherit Item (a, b, ' ', Color.White, Color.White)
    override this.FullyOccupy() = true
    override this.InteractWith (p: Player) =
        let mutable posX = p.X
        let mutable posY = p.Y
        let rand = System.Random()
        posX <- rand.Next()
        posY <- rand.Next()
```

Can someone maybe explain why it is not working?

It is supposed to work as a teleporter in a game, where if the player moves to the first (a,b) should be transported to a new (random) (a,b) position.
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the F# community. You need to move `let rand = System.Random()` outside the  `InteractWith` method, because it is probably initializing the same random sequence every time you call your `InteractWith` method. Also the `posX` and `posY` variables are probably not helpful.

Comment: Welcome to the F# community! Here is a general tip: if you find yourself writing object-oriented F# code, and it's not due to interop with C# or existing libraries, you're doing it wrong. Either use the functional subset of F# (and experience enlightenment!) or use an object-oriented language like C# and save yourself a few headaches.

Comment: @Arshia001, I believe you are wrong. F# is a multi-paradigm language, not a pure functional language. True, it is functional first, at least in the details. Still, on the higher level, object-oriented programming is an important part of F#, in particular with regards to organizing code, and makes the language a pragmatic solution to effective programming on the .NET platform.

Comment: @BentTranberg the comment might be overly general, but it's very applicable at least in this case.

Comment: @Arshia001. Citing Don Syme, the creator of F#. "F# is a “functional-first” language, where functional programming is the first option used for solving most
programming problems. However, F# differs from many functional languages in that it is both highly interoperable and embraces imperative and object-oriented (OO) programming where necessary.". One of the selling points of F# (and OCaml) besides being able to use .net libraries, is the fact that they are not purely functional, and support imperative (and OOP) when needed.

Comment: @RazielMagius quoting yourself here: ""F# is a “functional-first” language...  is both highly interoperable and embraces imperative and object-oriented (OO) programming **where necessary**." I take this to mean that you *should try* to write functional code with F#, and only write OO style *where necessary*. I am in no way claiming that the OO subset of F# is useless, I'm just saying the meat of your code shouldn't be in OO style. Otherwise, you're in for quite a few headaches because, as you know, F# doesn't support behavior inheritance (no `protected` keyword).

Comment: @BentTranberg One criticism F# always receives is how fidgety and unnatural its OO syntax feels. Personally, I've been writing F# for over two years now, and still find the need to search MSDN for the particular syntax to achieve a specific task in OO style. I believe this is intentional. F# lets you do everything, but makes you take the walk of shame for stuff you weren't really supposed to be doing that much. So, I'll have to disagree with you about code organization; it's perfectly possible in functional style.

Comment: The real problem, I believe, is that OO is the *industry standard* these days, so everybody thinks in OO. To really benefit from functional languages, we as a community need to stop thinking in OO. It'll be a whole new world once we start thinking functionally; so much so that some will be left wondering how they ever wrote any OO code at all (myself included). The true value of F# is that it enables that world over a mature and comprehensive (albeit OO) framework. You *need* OO style for interop with said framework, but it shouldn't be what you always write.

Comment: Don Syme on "[object programming](https://youtu.be/1AZA1zoP-II?t=2285)" in F#. (YouTube)

Answer (score 2):

The reason your code doesn't work is that it never mutates the `Player`'s position; `InteractWith` just copies the position into two local variables, and updates those.

This said, I strongly encourage you not to program in the OO-style if you want to learn F# - you'll be much happier going for a functional style.

One of the hallmarks of functional programming (FP) is immutability. For your teleport-thingy, this means NOT to mutate the `Player`'s position, but to create a new player with the new position.

Try something along the following line

```
type Player = { X: int; Y: int; Name: string }

let teleport player =
    let rand = System.Random()
    { player with X = rand.Next 100
                  Y = rand.Next 100 }
```

Also, try not to reach for a class as the solution for every problem, reach for a function instead; in the above, `teleport` is just a function `Player -> Player`.

I truly hope you'll enjoy F#; it's a great language for doing FP on .NET.